# How To Do Double Exposure Videos

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, compositing-nodes

I want to take two videos and add them together to make a double exposure.  How?   It would take hours to figure it out.

I know very little.   All I can do is load in the two vids.  I can't even figure out how to delete the soundtrack I don't want.

Comment: search on how to use the Video Sequence Editor (VSE) and yes, learning things takes hours

Answer (score 1):

You select the top strip, go to the sidebar panel, compositing, blend, and select alpha over:
[image]

To delete a sound strip, select the strip and hit Delete key(or go to the Strip menu and find delete).

To learn about using the VSE try watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXs21UilNYQ